# How to send a POST using Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, cucumber, protractor

So, I am trying to hit an endpoint with a POST through Protractor. I have wrote many different variations of the same code trying to get it to work.

So I used 'request' as my http client seemed most popular, and found other http clients, and thought about trying those, if I can't get this one to work.

I also use cucumber, and chai-as-promise. So the result of running this is nothing. So when I run this cucumber test and it goes through this When function it doesn't do the request.post. It just moves on to the next step. No Errors displayed in console. I used a REST client to do a GET to check if the POST worked, and noticed it did not work.
I need some help to troubleshoot why it is doing that.

will it make a difference If I were to put the post request into a function in a class somewhere else. and I called it sending it proper variables?

Here is the code:

```
    this.When(/^I test this$/, function (next) {
        var request = require('request');
        var options = {
            headers: {
                'id': 'AQ8WHWC',
                'sessionid': 'XnINW5KDQg=',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-us',
                'random': 'BS3P5Q'
            },
            form: { "pay_load": [] }
        };
        request.post('http://myurl.com/endpoint/test/', options, callback);

        function callback(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var info = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log(info);
            }
        }
browser.sleep(1).then(next)
    });
```

Output of console of running the cucumber test:

```
 Scenario: this is a cool test
  # endpoint/test/testing.feature:7
    Given I run this endpoint test
  # endpoint/test/testing.feature:8
    When I test this                                             
  # endpoint/test/testing.feature:9
    Then I see this                                    
  # endpoint/test/testing.feature:10

1 scenario (1 passed)
3 steps (3 passed)
[launcher] chrome passed

Done, without errors.
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No errors at all from the console. It shows all green in the test. But when I run a GET from an rest client. I see the POST did not work.

Comment: I added console output

Comment: seriously no on one?
at least provide an example of what you did instead. I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue to be my syntax of using npm request.

This stuff can be very picky.
I used to the custom request option which offered: request(object, object)

I ended up doing the following to make it work:

```
    var request = require('request');

    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://myurl.com/endpoint/test/',
        headers: {'id': 'AQ8WHWC',
            'sessionid': 'XnINW5KDQg=',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-us',
            'random': 'BS3P5Q'
        },
        body: '{ "pay_load": [] }'
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var info = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(response);
            console.log(info);
        }
    }
    request(options, callback);
};
```

Comment: How  to send the data in the request body of the POST method, like if I have to send a object to the request body of the method of the server

Comment: not sure what your question is. Can you explain with a bit more detail. Basically the function I written works with a package called npm request. And that package is essentially a REST client. I am mimicking a REST client. sending an http POST. Everything the browser would normally do.

Comment: I want to send a JSON object to the POST method , but I dnt know how to do that exactly

Comment: I'm still new to javascript. but my guess would be to do this: 1) obtain json object. 2) parse json object to how you need it to send the POST. 3) where you see body: json_object_goes_here. (You may need to create another function to create the properfly formated json object to be added into the body. hope this helps. (basically, I hardcoded the 'body:' value, but you can of course turn it into a variable to pass an object to it.)